# Capturing Wait Statistics

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Based on https://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/sql-server-performance-tuning-using-wait-statistics-a-beginners-guide/ (page 34), I'm trying to create table and fill it with Wait Stats.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [sys].[tables]
    WHERE   [name]=N'WaitStats'AND[type] =N'U'
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_WaitStats](
[RowNum] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
[CaptureDate] [DATETIME] ,
[WaitType] [NVARCHAR](120) ,
[Wait_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2) ,
[Resource_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2),
[Signal_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2) ,
[WaitCount] [BIGINT] ,
[Percentage] [DECIMAL](4, 2) ,
[AvgWait_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2),
[AvgRes_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2),
[AvgSig_S] [DECIMAL](14, 2));

GO


INSERT  INTO dbo.T_WaitStats([WaitType])
    VALUES  ('Wait Statistics for '+ CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(19)));

INSERT  INTO dbo.T_WaitStats( 
    [CaptureDate],
    [WaitType],
    [Wait_S],
    [Resource_S],
    [Signal_S],
    [WaitCount],
    [Percentage],
    [AvgWait_S],
    [AvgRes_S],
    [AvgSig_S]
)

EXEC(
    'WITH [Waits] AS(
        SELECT
            [wait_type],
            [wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [Wait_S],
            ([wait_time_ms] - [signal_wait_time_ms]) / 1000.0 AS [Resource_S],
            [signal_wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [Signal_S],
            [waiting_tasks_count] AS [WaitCount],
            100.0 * [wait_time_ms] / SUM ([wait_time_ms]) OVER() AS [Percentage],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [wait_time_ms] DESC) AS [RowNum]
        FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
        WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
            N''BROKER_EVENTHANDLER'',   N''BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR'',
            N''BROKER_TASK_STOP'',      N''BROKER_TO_FLUSH'',
            N''BROKER_TRANSMITTER'',    N''CHECKPOINT_QUEUE'',
            N''CHKPT'',                 N''CLR_AUTO_EVENT'', 
            N''CLR_MANUAL_EVENT''       
        )
    )
    SELECT      
        GETDATE() AS [CaptureDate],
        [W1].[wait_type] AS [WaitType], 
        CAST ([W1].[Wait_S] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Wait_S],
        CAST ([W1].[Resource_S] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Resource_S],
        CAST ([W1].[Signal_S] AS DECIMAL(14, 2)) AS [Signal_S],
        [W1].[WaitCount] AS [WaitCount],
        CAST ([W1].[Percentage] AS DECIMAL(4, 2)) AS [Percentage],
        CAST (([W1].[Wait_S] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4))
                                                    AS [AvgWait_S],
        CAST (([W1].[Resource_S] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4))
                                                    AS [AvgWait_S],
        CAST (([W1].[Resource_S] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4))
                                                    AS [AvgRes_S],
        CAST (([W1].[Signal_S] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4))
                                                    AS [AvgSig_S]
    FROM [Waits] AS [W1]
    INNER JOIN [Waits] AS [W2]
        ON [W2].[RowNum] <= [W1].[RowNum]
    GROUP BY [W1].[RowNum], [W1].[wait_type], [W1].[Wait_S], 
        [W1].[Resource_S], [W1].[Signal_S], [W1].[WaitCount],
        [W1].[Percentage]
    HAVING SUM ([W2].[Percentage]) - [W1].[Percentage] < 95;'
);
```

First insert works, but second give me an error:

> (1 row(s) affected) Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1 Column name or
>   number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Running second statement without insert (only EXEC part) works.
What might cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy-paste in your query (returns 11 columns, but table expected 10 columns)

```
CAST (([W1].[Resource_S] / [W1].[WaitCount]) AS DECIMAL (14, 4)) AS [AvgWait_S],
```

query -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.T_WaitStats', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.T_WaitStats
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_WaitStats] (
    RowNum INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CaptureDate DATETIME,
    WaitType NVARCHAR(120),
    Wait_S DECIMAL(14,2),
    Resource_S DECIMAL(14,2),
    Signal_S DECIMAL(14,2),
    WaitCount BIGINT,
    Percentage DECIMAL(4,2),
    AvgWait_S DECIMAL(14,2),
    AvgRes_S DECIMAL(14,2),
    AvgSig_S DECIMAL(14,2)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.T_WaitStats ([WaitType])
VALUES ('Wait Statistics for ' + CAST(GETDATE() AS NVARCHAR(19)))

INSERT INTO dbo.T_WaitStats (CaptureDate, WaitType, Wait_S, Resource_S, Signal_S, WaitCount, Percentage, AvgWait_S, AvgRes_S, AvgSig_S)
EXEC ('WITH [Waits] AS(
        SELECT
            [wait_type],
            [wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [Wait_S],
            ([wait_time_ms] - [signal_wait_time_ms]) / 1000.0 AS [Resource_S],
            [signal_wait_time_ms] / 1000.0 AS [Signal_S],
            [waiting_tasks_count] AS [WaitCount],
            100.0 * [wait_time_ms] / SUM ([wait_time_ms]) OVER() AS [Percentage],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [wait_time_ms] DESC) AS [RowNum]
        FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
        WHERE [wait_type] NOT IN (
            N''BROKER_EVENTHANDLER'',   N''BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR'',
            N''BROKER_TASK_STOP'',      N''BROKER_TO_FLUSH'',
            N''BROKER_TRANSMITTER'',    N''CHECKPOINT_QUEUE'',
            N''CHKPT'',                 N''CLR_AUTO_EVENT'', 
            N''CLR_MANUAL_EVENT''       
        )
    )
    SELECT      
        GETDATE() AS [CaptureDate],
        [W1].[wait_type] AS [WaitType], 
        [W1].[Wait_S] AS [Wait_S],
        [W1].[Resource_S] AS [Resource_S],
        [W1].[Signal_S] AS [Signal_S],
        [W1].[WaitCount] AS [WaitCount],
        [W1].[Percentage] AS [Percentage],
        [W1].[Wait_S] / [W1].[WaitCount] AS [AvgWait_S],
        [W1].[Resource_S] / [W1].[WaitCount] AS [AvgRes_S],
        [W1].[Signal_S] / [W1].[WaitCount] AS [AvgSig_S]
    FROM [Waits] AS [W1]
    INNER JOIN [Waits] AS [W2]
        ON [W2].[RowNum] <= [W1].[RowNum]
    GROUP BY [W1].[RowNum], [W1].[wait_type], [W1].[Wait_S], 
        [W1].[Resource_S], [W1].[Signal_S], [W1].[WaitCount],
        [W1].[Percentage]
    HAVING SUM ([W2].[Percentage]) - [W1].[Percentage] < 95;'
);
```